# mysql populating multiple select drop down

Tags: mysql, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate a few select drop down lists from mysql, but each drop down is from a different table.
When I do the following:

```
$data_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_sql)){
  $countrylist .= '<option value="'.$data[country_iso].'">'.$data[country].'</option>';
}
```

All Works fine. But when I get into adding more tables as follows:

```
$data_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries, states");
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($data_sql)){
  $countrylist .= '<option value="'.$data[country_iso].'">'.$data[country].'</option>';
  $statelist .= '<option value="'.$data[state_iso].'">'.$data[state].'</option>';
}
```

My drop downs work but have each row repeated 3 times.

Comment: You should execute two queries, and the second **only after** the user has made a choice for the country he wants to pick. Otherwise, which country's states do you use for the states drop down? For getting the data to populate the states list you can either use an ajax call, or a very big json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stumbled on a implicit [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_join), while you want a <del>`UNION`</del>

```
SELECT * FROM countries
UNION 
SELECT * states
```

What your current query (`SELECT * FROM countries, states`) does, is the following: For every row in countries, combine the data from this country with all states.

This would mean that if you have 10 countries, and 10 states, the total number of rows would be 100. Count yourself lucky you did a cartesian join on a very small table :)

You just want to do 2 queries separately: trying to combine the results isn't nearly as effective as 2 separate ones.

Comment: So then would I write the query as `$data_sql("SELECT * FROM countries UNION SELECT * states");` and also can I union more than just one table?

Comment: Scratch the UNION bit: I now see you don't want that. Just do 2 queries, trust me ;)

Comment: Well I had originally had it with multiple queries but my hosting company said I needed to cut down on my amount of separate calls to mysql, which I didn't believe in php it did, I was under the impression that one connect query just kept that same one connection open.

Comment: If that's the problem, store this in an array instead- cut the queries by ∞% :)

Comment: It usually keeps one connection open, unless you explicitly close it. If they are complaining about opening & closing a connection, they surely aren't going to be happy about these queries :). I assume you only use 1 `mysql_connect` per page load, and just multiple `mysql_query`s after that? In that case, caching results and / or optimizing queries might be the better way to go.

Comment: Yeah, I use one predefined header and footer, which the header holds the connection and the footer closes the connection.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case, either you are to popular, your host is to cheap, or there's something weird going on. But as @therealsix said, nothing wrong with caching seldomly changing data. Also, you may want to abstract your database away so that the connection is only opened at the first query, saving open/closing on pageloads which don't need a database connection.